# Backbone get model from id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Below is a model in my collection, how can I extract it from the collection - finding it by the id?

I usually do it with:

```
var twitter_id = window.localStorage.getItem("twitter_id");
AttoriBackEnd.twitter.fetch({nome:nomecercato,type:'twitter'});
AttoreTwitter= AttoriBackEnd.twitter.get(twitter_id);
```

But now it doesn't extract anything (I'm using backbone 1.1.2, with another version it worked perfectly).

```
models: Array[4]
 0: child
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c50"
collection: child
id: "8696369"
```

Answer (score 0):

***Simply just use built-in method for collection (findWhere)***

To return single model that match twitter_id from collection

```
AttoreTwitter = AttoriBackEnd.twitter.findWhere({
    // If model's id is twitter_id then
    id: twitter_id
    // else if model's twitter_id is set on model itself then
    twitter_id: twitter_id
});
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see, I feel like you need to wait til `fetch` completes then you can get the certain model in the collection. Here's one way to do it:

```
var twitter_id = window.localStorage.getItem("twitter_id");
AttoriBackEnd.twitter.fetch({nome:nomecercato,type:'twitter'});

var AttoreTwitter;
AttoriBackEnd.twitter.on('sync', function(){
  AttoreTwitter= AttoriBackEnd.twitter.get(twitter_id);
  console.log(AttoreTwitter); // Test to see
  // Continue code here
});
```